# Set useState variable to another variable?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I have two useState variables:

```
const [varOne, setVarOne] = useState(null);
const [varTwo, setVarTwo] = useState(null);
```

And a third variable that tells me which variables I need to use, varOne or varTwo:

```
const [whichVar, setWhichVar] = useState(0);
```

And I have a third variable `curVar` which will be either varOne or varTwo based on the value of `whichVar`:

```
const [curVar, setCurVar] = useState(null);
if (whichVar === 0) {
  curVar = varOne;
  setCurVar = setVarOne;
} else {
  curVar = varTwo;
  setCurVar = setVarTwo;
}
```

However I highly doubt this is the best way to do this. How would you suggest I approach this problem?

Comment: Maybe check out [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer), or write a separate function that handles the state updates simultaneously instead of calling setVarOne directly.

Comment: var one and two could be an array and which var could be the index.

Comment: Im not a senior so dont take this for granted but here is my opinion about your current method. `curVar` is useless. Its basically a copy of whatever is one of the other values. I would remove it. The `varOne` and `varTwo` I would put into a single array variable and then `whichVar` would be a key to witch of the vars to use. This way you tone down on `if` statements as you could simple do `vars[whichVar]` and would be easily expandible to how ever amount of vars you need. You could use a reducer but if just a simple component logic for like text render then i wouldint.

Comment: Thank you, yes I agree, using an array would be the best option

Comment: The reducer idea could be even better.

Comment: Why do you think the useReducer could be better? Using an array seems the simplest and achieves what I want to do?

Comment: How would you use useReducer for something like this?